# ADB doesn't recognize Samsung S5830(Ace) in Linux Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I can't use Galaxy ACE with adb, here's what I see when I try to run app:
[image]

On Windows 7 I've installed Kies and everything went fine. But I can't find driver for linux.
Any help?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add udev rules described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: Thanks for response. I've done what is written in docs, but still see the same picture.

Comment: Solved. Tried also this http://dimitar.me/how-to-connect-your-android-phone-to-ubuntu-to-do-developmenttestinginstallations-or-tethering/ and re-connected device to usb.

Comment: You need to be sure that find the correct USB Vendor ID for your Wearable. For example, for the LG G you need to use Google's instead of LG's vendor ID.. see http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2014/12/udev-for-android-wear.html

Comment: @vorburger Thank you. Saved my day.