# adb devices list empty ubuntu 12.04 s5830

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-12.04

My problem is that adb devices does not detect my galaxy ace (s5830) using Ubuntu 12.04,
 I tried everything but still not working.
Can help me where fault.
I have installed oracle sdk 1.7, last android sdk and I have created the rule 51-android.rules with permissions a+r

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650617/adb-doesnt-recognize-samsung-s5830ace-in-linux-ubuntu-10-04 ?

Comment: @Matthieu, I think he already saw that because he already has the udev 51-android.rules set up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Despite the rules file my device was not getting detected. 
I did the following:

1. Restarted my device
2. Connected as "Charge only" (an HTC device).

The device was detected and I was able to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things

1. Download [Kies](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Telephony-SMS-GSM/Kies.shtml)  for Samsung Smart Phone
2. Restart eclipse
3. In DDMS section, go windows->Show View->Devices, then click small down arrow(View Menu) and click on Reset ADB. Then it should work properly...

Comment: Kies wasn't made for Ubuntu. On linux, we use udev rules.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses Java 1.6, so upgrading to 1.7 wasn't necessary.

Did you really use the Samsung vendor id 04e8 for your udev rules? And did you set debugging "on" on your actual device? Do you have any tethering app on your device (that makes use of adb)? Some do.

Also you need to restart your terminal window (or restart Eclipse) for your udev rules to be loaded for the first time, but I assume you did that already.

Also for good measure, you should restart your device as well.

If you're really desperate to get this working, you could always root your phone and use a free app like adbwireless (which only works on rooted devices and local wifi which does not have wifi isolation turned on). That's what I had to do with my Samsung Tab 10.1 (until I sent it back for repair).

Adb wasn't finding my Tab from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop either, nor was it finding it from the Mac and the Windows PC of my developer friends, but when I tried to connect the Samsung Tab 10.1 that belonged to a friend of mine, adb was seeing it just fine on it, so this is what pinpointed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no wifi, long ago got it to work but I do not remember exactly as I did.
It has to work.

Comment: Factory resetting your device may help. At least, it did for me a little bit for my Samsung Tab, although the adb connection wasn't stable. Also, trying with a different cable of the same type can help make a difference in some cases as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting adb

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Make yourself a shortcut to this.

Comment: Sorry but the problem is more complicated