# Debug Android Wear Device over USB

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

Is this possible to debug wear device over USB, not Bluetooth?
By Bluetooth it is possible, but when i'm connecting watch to PC via USB, in adb i have:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
????????????    no permissions
```

Comment: Put the bluetooth permission in your manifest?

Comment: It will depend on the Wear device (not all offer USB). From there, it should be no different than any other Android device (e.g., on Windows, you need to find the correct driver).

Comment: If you are on Linux, also check out the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650617/adb-doesnt-recognize-samsung-s5830ace-in-linux-ubuntu-10-04.

Answer (score 12):

I use Ubuntu 14.10 as OS and had to run these steps to get my Wear recognized (source: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, under step 3):

1. Get your Wear's vendor ID from here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds
2. Log in as root and create this file: **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**
3. Add this line, and replace ???? by your Vendor ID:
   `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="????", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`
4. Save and execute **chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**
5. Reconnect your Wear, and wait for the Permission-Dialog to show (on your Mobile!)

**EDIT:**

[here](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules/blob/master/51-android.rules) is a complete `51-android.rules` file to allow any kind of android device

Answer (score 5):

Restart ADB with root privileges.

```
sudo killall adb
sudo adb
```

Comment: In my case just restarting adb was sufficient i.e. sudo not required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow **ADB debugging** in **Developer options** on Wear device, and after you connect watch-PC by USB you will be prompted on the phone to "allow USB debugging for particular PC", you click yes and your smartwatch should be visible on adb list, also you should see log and be able to deploy apps right away - just as any phone in debugging mode.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is, that there is no prompt. I allowed ADB debugging, connected wear device to PC but nothing happend. In 'adb devices' there is only '?????? no permissions'

Comment: Try that you allows debugging on the phone and connect to PC, maybe it is the case. And then try with wear.